# Can a pillow destroy a window?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, everyday-life

Say we have a steel ball and a pillow. If they both have the same kinetic energy when colliding with a window, do they do the same damage? Is it even possible for a pillow to destroy a window with any amount of kinetic energy?

Comment: Example: https://www.space.com/19436-columbia-disaster.html

Answer (score 3):

The parameter we need to look at is not primarily the kinetic energy of the projectile but the stress  (more precisely, the change in stress over a distance or orientation) induced in the window. It's the applied stress that governs whether a crack will propagate in the brittle glass.

Let's look at two extremes. First, I could walk up to the window and break it by gently pressing a very sharp ceramic (e.g., from a [broken sparkplug](https://lifehacker.com/shatter-a-car-window-with-a-sparkplug-in-an-emergency-1540780900)) into it. Here, the kinetic energy is essentially zero. However, the very sharp tip induces a high stress concentration in the glass that can induce one or more cracks to propagate.

Second, in the other extreme, I could expose a window to extremely high hydrostatic pressure and nothing will happen because the stress is uniform. The windows of sunken ships aren't pulverized, for example, just because they're under very high stresses at the bottom of the sea. This is because no stress gradient exists—the pressure is applied from all directions.

Let's go back to the steel ball and the pillow. It's certainly the case that a pillow, given enough kinetic energy, can break glass because the colliding pillow wouldn't apply a stress from all directions; thus, a stress gradient will always be created. Whether a steel ball or a pillow with a given kinetic energy is more likely to break a window, however, depends on how large a stress concentration is created at the point of contact and at the mounting points of the window, and I'm not sure we can say without more information whether one or the other would be more destructive.

Comment: Besides exerting less pressure due to the larger contact area, a pillow also deforms way more easily than a steel ball - and that significantly increases impact time, thus reducing peak impact force, as well as dissipating some of the energy.

Answer (score 2):

A steel ball hits the window at a single point and the force onset is abrupt. Its destructive power is aided by the inertia of the glass away from the impact. High frequency waves are created that locally bend the glass. Along intrinsic weaknesses and stress region of the glass it will break. If the ball is fast enough it will even leave a round hole.

A perfect pillow will distribute the force of impact equally over the glass surface. It will act like a quasistatic air pressure difference between the two sides of the glass. If this pressure difference is high enough is large enough the glass will break.